# How to parse HTML string into HTML DOM elements in python?

Tags: jquery, python, html, dom

I've a string of HTML elements

```
HTMLstr = """
    <div class='column span4 ui-sortable' id='column1'></div>
    <div class='column span4 ui-sortable' id='column2'>
        <div class='portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all' id='widget_basicLine'>
        <div class='portlet-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>Line Chart </div>
        <div class='portlet-content' id=basicLine style='height:270px; margin: 0 auto;'></div>          
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column span4 ui-sortable' id='column3'></div> """
```

I want to convert the above HTML string into respective HTML DOM elements in python?

I can do it in jQuery/AJAX function via `$(this).html(HTMLstr);` but how do I parse it in python?

Comment: Have you got any python code you've tried? Any libraries you've already looked at? What worked, what didn't?

Comment: try html dom parser. http://thehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I havent used any library yet. I'm sending the HTMLstr from backend(python) to the front end. I want to parse the HTMLstr into its equivalent HTMLDOM elements from the python only. How can I do it?

Comment: @Pradeeshnarayan - This could've worked but I'm using python 2.7. and it requires python 3.2

Comment: -1: Given the comments from OP on the answers, OP did not actually want to do anything in Python and does not really seem to understand what they want.

Answer (score 6):

Python has built-in libraries for parsing HTML documents. In Python 2.x, you have your choice of [`HTMLParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) (recommended) and [`htmllib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmllib.html) (deprecated); in Python 3.x, [`html.parser`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/html.parser.html) is the appropriate library (this is a renamed version of `HTMLParser` from Python 2.x).

However, these are event-driven parsers (similar to XML SAX parsers), which may not be what you want. An alternative would be using one of Python's XML parsing tools, if you know that the document is going to be valid XML (i.e. tags properly closed, etc.). The libraries [`xml.dom`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html) and [`xml.dom.minidom`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) are both options, depending on what kind of parsing you're looking for (I suspect [`xml.dom.minidom`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) is sufficient for your purposes, given your example).

For example, you should be able to enter this in your Python console and get the output shown:

```
>>> import xml.dom.minidom
>>> x = xml.dom.minidom.parseString('<div class="column span4 ui-sortable" id="column2"><div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" id="widget_basicLine" /></div>')
>>> x.documentElement.nodeName
'div'
>>> x.documentElement.getAttribute("class")
'column span4 ui-sortable'
>>> len(x.documentElement.firstChild.childNodes)
0
```

A full description of the Node objects you receive is available [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#dom-node-objects). If you're used to using the DOM in JavaScript, you should find that most of the properties are the same. Note that because Python treats this as an XML document, HTML-specific properties like 'class' have no special significance, so I believe you have to use the `getAttribute` function to access them.

Comment: The Python documentation has an example [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html#example-html-parser-application). However, it occurs to me that [`HTMLParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) is event-driven rather than the DOM parser from your example, so you might be better off with one of the XML parsers. For `xml.dom.minidom`, the relevant calls are either `xml.dom.minidom.parse` (for files) or `xml.dom.minidom.parseString` (for strings of markup).

Comment: Still not able able to get the correct o/p required. Can you please provide a working example.

Comment: I've added an example above - hopefully this will help. If it doesn't, can you give me more details about the problem you are seeing?

Comment: I guess you havent understood my question. I have created a string(shown above) and I return this string from python to the front end. On the front-end browser, I get the plain text of string, instead I want the string to be parsed into equivalent HTML elements and render the output accordingly. 

How do I do that?

Comment: Well, you're right - I'm definitely confused. If what you want to do is take a string of text representing HTML and transform it into HTML elements to be inserted into the web page in jQuery, isn't that done with the expression `$(this).html(HTMLstr);` that you used when asking the question? If you want to use the output as HTML without going through this step, I'm not sure that's possible - you can use the `responseXML` property of the AJAX request object, but the elements would belong to a different document and in my experience browsers don't let you easily move them over.

Comment: Since this HTMLstr loads when the page is loaded(not AJAX request), hence I cannot use `$(this).html(HTMLstr);`. Can I?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work - the `html` function in jQuery can be used any time (i.e. it doesn't have any special connection to AJAX). Just replace `$(this)` with a jQuery call to get the element that you want to insert the HTML into and it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should use BeautifulSoup -- does exactly what you need.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: I tried this and it returns the same string , not the HTML elements.

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlstr = "<div class='column span4 ui-sortable' id='column2'><div class='portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all' id='widget_basicLine'><div class='portlet-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>Line Chart </div><div class='portlet-content' id=basicLine style='height:270px; margin: 0 auto;'></div></div></div>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlstr)
return soup`

Comment: What are you trying to do? How did you determine it's a string object and not some other more complex object?

Comment: I have created a string(shown above) and I return this string from python to the front end. On the front-end browser, I get the plain text of string, instead I want the string to be parsed into equivalent HTML elements and render the output accordingly. How do I do that?

Comment: Its a string object only. I've created this string of HTML elements as  a string object. Now, I want to convert/parse this string into its equivalent HTML elements. How do I do that?